# springboot postgresql create data without sequence

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

```
jdk1.8.0_202.jdk
psql -V 12.1
```

There is a problem creating and saving a postgresql object. When trying to create the object's id value is empty. I don't know why. Please tell me what to check.

```
package com.interpark.lab.tour.geolocation.model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "expedia_region_union")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
public class ExpediaRegionUnion {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false )
    private String regionId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "region_type")
    private String regionType;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "region_name")
    private String regionName;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "region_name_full")
    private String regionNameFull;

    @Transient
    private String regionDescriptor;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "coordinates")
    private String coordinates;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "center_longitude")
    private String centerLongitude;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "center_latitude")
    private String centerLatitude;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "continent")
    private HashMap continent;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "add_continent")
    private List addContinent;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "ancestors")
    private String ancestors;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "descendants")
    private String descendants;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "region_name_kr")
    private String regionNameKr;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "region_name_full_kr")
    private String regionNameFullKr;

    @Transient
    @Column(columnDefinition = "parent_city_flag")
    private String parentCityFlag;

    @Transient
    @Column(columnDefinition = "parent_city")
    private String parentCity;

    @Transient
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boundaries")
    private Geometry boundaries;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "country")
    private HashMap country;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "city_ancestors")
    private String cityAncestors;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ancestors_info")
    private List ancestorsInfo;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "synonym")
    private String synonym;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "coordinates_nearby")
    private String coordinatesNearby;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "coordinates_nearby_auto")
    private String coordinatesNearbyAuto;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nearest_airport")
    private HashMap nearestAirport;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nearest_airport_in_country")
    private HashMap nearestAirportInCountry;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "codes")
    private HashMap codes;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "airport")
    private List airport;

    @Transient
    private String countryCodeLower;

    @Transient
    @Type(type = "boolean")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "display")
    private Boolean display;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonn")
    private HashMap jsonn;

    @Column(name = "jsonn_updated", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
    private Boolean jsonnUpdated;

    @Column(name = "in_use", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
    private Boolean inUse;

    @Column(name = "source_time")
    private String sourceTime;

    @Column(name = "city_home_flag")
    private String cityHomeFlag;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "source_from")
    private String sourceFrom;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "region_code")
    private String regionCode;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "sub_class")
    private String subClass;

    @Transient
    private boolean selected;

}
```

I don't know why but, like this, When inserting, the region_id value is empty.

```
Hibernate: insert into expedia_region_union (add_continent, airport, ancestors, ancestors_info, center_latitude, center_longitude, city_ancestors, city_home_flag, codes, continent, coordinates, coordinates_nearby, coordinates_nearby_auto, country, country_code, descendants, in_use, jsonn, jsonn_updated, nearest_airport, nearest_airport_in_country, region_code, region_name, region_name_full, region_name_full_kr, region_name_kr, region_type, source_from, source_time, sub_class, synonym) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

What I don't understand is, as you can see below, it's made and put in like other things.

```
public void save(Map paramBean) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ExpediaRegionUnion insert = new ExpediaRegionUnion();
        insert.setRegionId("INTERPARK" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        insert.setRegionType(paramBean.get("regionType") + "");
        insert.setRegionName(paramBean.get("regionName") + "");
```

Can't I create an object without using auto increment? Because I thought I didn't need a sequence. Please let me know if I am wrong.

```
Hibernate: select currval('expedia_region_union_region_id_seq')
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
오류: "expedia_region_union_region_id_seq" 이름의 릴레이션(relation)이 없습니다
```

Why hibernate wants sequences that I don't even need?

Comment: The problem comes from the fact you want to use a UUID as a primary key. The postgresql sequences are not made for this. Have a look here on how to implement it : https://vladmihalcea.com/uuid-identifier-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: @OlivierDepriester hmm... Thanks for the quick advice. I've already thought about this. So I tried changing from uuid to region_id but it didn't work. Could you please tell me in more detail if possible?

Comment: You mean you could use a numeric id instead of a uuid ?

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Umm.. no I mean, I just changed "columnDefinition =" uuid "" to "columnDefinition =" region_id "" ... that did not work. Isn't that what you're saying is to change the columnDefinition?

Comment: No : using the ```@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)``` annotation makes Hibernate try to use a ```expedia_region_union_region_id_seq``` sequence to generate a numeric id. Impossible for you. You must use ```@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)``` and then implement/configure a UUID generator if you want your DB to generate it. The url I quoted above explains really well how to do it

Comment: @OlivierDepriester Thanks a lot for the quick and friendly answer. I've organized your answers and the information in that url to suit my situation. Can you look at my answer?

Comment: @OlivierDepriester 
Also I have an additional question, if it does not bother you, can you explain the difference between PK and Sequence clearly?

Comment: Sorry I was out and I totally forgot your question :p. A PK is only a constraint you set on a table to identify a row and that will be referenced by your foreign keys in other tables. It can consists of 1 or more columns (ie for a ```Clothes``` table it could be {model, size, color}.

Comment: When your PK is as simple a being a numeric technical Id, you can set your ID value when you insert data in your table (it is up to you to handle the ID values to be unique) or for some DB engines set this PK field as AutoIncrement (mysql, sqlserver) or for other engines (postgres, oracle) you can create a sequence in your DB which is actually a counter whose can be used to set the PK value

Answer (score 0):

I delegated primary key generation to the database using  `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. But I shouldn't have done that. **Because the data in my table already created were not auto-incremented numeric ids. They were based on the Openstreetmap's local id.** I write answers for such people.

as @Olivier Depriester says, using `GenerationType.AUTO` works well. I followed this article.

https://vladmihalcea.com/uuid-identifier-jpa-hibernate/

This is how I create uuid directly through a class in springboot without leaving pk creation in the database.

> 1. in psql, you type this.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

that extension makes you uuid-generator.

> 2. you just copy this. Place the files in the appropriate directory.

```
public class PostgreSQLUUIDGenerationStrategy
    implements UUIDGenerationStrategy {

    @Override
    public int getGeneratedVersion() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID generateUUID(
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {
        return ((Session) session).doReturningWork(connection -> {
            try(
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
                    "select uuid_generate_v4()"
                )
            ) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    return (UUID) resultSet.getObject(1);
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't fetch a new UUID");
        });
    }
}
```

> 3. in your entity class, you change configuration.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
            generator = "pg-uuid"
    )
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "pg-uuid",
            strategy = "uuid2",
            parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                    name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                    value = "whatever.your.package.PostgresQLUUIDGenerationUtils"
            )
    )
    private String regionId;
```

and this is mine.